# cannot access docker on wsl2 with its IP address

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to follow:
https://dev.to/_nicolas_louis_/how-to-run-docker-on-windows-without-docker-desktop-hik
in order to use docker on wsl2 from Windows.

I can start a docker container with this call:

```
docker -H 127.0.0.1 run --rm hello-world
```

however, when I obtain the IP address with:

```
echo `ifconfig eth0 | grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | cut -f2 -d:`
```

and try to start the container with:

```
docker -H 172.26.110.78 run --rm hello-world
```

I get the following error:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://172.26.110.78:2375. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

Ping works and docker daemon runs, obviously.

What can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score -1):

try restarting your docker container as it might be not running in a proper state.
Use:

```
 docker restart [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
```

For Example:

```
docker restart hello_world
```

Comment: restarted several times and it never worked.